# How to get Visual Studio to display the real Vue.js error? "The command npm run build exited with code 1.”

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, visual-studio-2017

I’m working in my first ever vue.js project, and I’m using Visual Studio 2017 as my IDE. Sometimes, when I try to run the site in debug mode, I get a very unhelpful error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command "
      npm run build
    " exited with code 1.   EIOBoardVueApp  D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 5147
```

I finally figured out that this isn’t the actual error. But, I’m not sure how to force Visual Studio to tell me what the actual error is. Has anyone every seen this before and figured out how to sniff out the real error?

(I've seen other threads on this error, but nothing that has lead me to a solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity. Change this to Detailed.

Then, when you try to debug the project, VS will still give you the useless error in the ErrorList window, but if you look in the Output window, the real error will be there:

[image]